# How to use relative domain name for each jooma 3.8 websites running on the same server

Tags: joomla-3.x, redirect, joomla3.8

Hello i run multiple joomla 3.8 websites on one server, each installed in there own directory. They are reachable from the internet via there own domain url.
On dns level i used a redirect from the relative-A-url.be -> absolute.be/A
and checked the box "display relative-A-url.be in the address bar on my browser".
This works fine for the first page, but when i open other links in my website i'll still see the absolute path, by example :
http://absolute.be/A/index.php/kalender/twijnen/registratie
where i'll expect
http://relative-A-url.be/index.php/kalender/twijnen/registratie
Mention that the link to my Joomla Admin console ONLY works via the following link http://absolute/A/administrator.

What is the best practice to solve so the site looks a relative-A-url.be website and is SEO ready ?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your hosting environment but I am usually able to fix this type of issue on Apache hosting using `Rewritebase` in the `.htaccess` file.

For example, if a website is in a subfolder like this: `/public_html/subfolder`, then include the following lines in the `/public_html/subfolder/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
Rewritebase /public_html/subfolder
```

Comment: Hello Neil, thanks for the reply, i'll tryed it but don't see any difference, I'm gonna setup a copy of the actual website as qa environment so i can test without screwing up the active website. brgrds, Marc

Comment: OK, I'll leave the answer in case it's useful for anyone else.